# Best way to send a cookie from the browser to the server in a CORS XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cookies, xmlhttprequest

Storing client session data as a cookie seems more secure than anything else, but I am not sure how to send/include the front-end cookie in a CORS AJAX request. I know I should set `withCredentials` to true on XmlHttpRequest, but other than that, I am not sure how the cookie actually gets sent to the server?

So on the Node.js server, I would send the cookie to the browser with

```
function(req,res,next){

   res.cookie('lectal-cookie', someEncryptedToken, {maxAge:'12h'});

}
```

on the client (browser), I assume that cookie is automatically stored somewhere-

but how do I include the cookie in a cross-origin AJAX request? Do I send it as a header or can I send it as a cookie or both?

Will using `withCredentials=true` automatically include all the browser cookies in the AJAX request?

Comment: To my knowledge, a sever cannot access cookie from other domains even with CORS

Comment: With my [experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171168/jquery-ajax-not-return-response-cors-fail), don't try this. When i must do this, my advance is "create proxy, and use it", maybe with php.

Comment: what do you mean by create proxy?

Comment: I just send it as part of the post request: `<form action="/profile/create?form=create&_csrf={{csrfToken}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.  You can do the same thing in an AJAX request.

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know if x.y.com is considered a different origin than z.y.com?

Comment: this answers that question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: strangely enough, the cookies get sent between localhost:5000 and localhost:5001, but they don't get sent across origins that are not localhost...